# HOW to declare NSDecimal and how to use NSDecimalAdd

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

somebody help,I tried whold afternoon and could't find the method to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035421/creating-nsdecimal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449422/how-do-i-add-nsdecimalnumbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDecimal` is a C-struct with private members, you would usually create one from the Objective-C class `NSDecimalNumber` (`decimalValue`).

However, using `NSDecimal` directly is rarely needed, dealing with `NSDecimalNumber` is much easier. You can use the `decimalNumberByAdding:` method instead of the `NSDecimalAdd` function.